# Is the vector function $\mathbf r(t) = \langle t^3, t^3 \rangle$ smooth at $t = 0$?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

This was confusing me when learning about curvature and smoothness. The condition for smoothness on interval $I$ is given as:

1. $\mathbf r'$ is continuous;
2. $\mathbf r'(t) \neq \mathbf 0$.

In this particular example, the space curve of this parametrization is just a straight line passing through the origin, but it follows that
$$\mathbf r'(t) = \langle 3t^2, 3t^2 \rangle$$
thus $\mathbf r'(0) = \mathbf 0$, meaning that $\mathbf r$ is not smooth at the origin. However, the space curve seems to be perfectly "smooth" and differentiable. What am I missing here?

(Also, by this definition the parametrization $\mathbf s(t) = \langle t, t \rangle$ with the same space curve is smooth at the origin. Why could they be different?)

Comment: What you've demonstrated here is that the smoothness of a vector function does not depend solely on the curve it produces. It depends on the function, i.e. the curve *and* the parameterisation of said curve. If you want a concept for smoothness of curves that is independent of parameterisation, you could say a curve is smooth if there exists a smooth parameterisation.

Comment: You should correct the derivative.

Comment: Where did you find this definition of "smooth"?

Comment: You seem to be bucking at the stipulation that $r'(t) \neq 0$. This seems a necessary addition to the definition, otherwise $(t|t|, t^2)$ would be a smooth vector function, tracing out a curve with an obvious cusp at $t = 0$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for the clarification! So is it more accurate to think that smoothness is actually based on the *process* of tracing out a space curve, not the shape or differentiability of the curve itself? It makes sense because $\mathbf r'(t) = \mathbf 0$ means the vector is stationary at this point, and my guess is that the vector could then potentially sharply turn to head any direction, causing non-smoothness. Also, it would be appreciated if you could formulate your explanation into an answer :)

Comment: @gpassante Corrected, sorry that I didn't notice earlier...

Comment: @PaulFrost In introductory calculus textbooks, the one I was using is *Calculus (8th edition)* by James Stewart. The definition is on page 903.

Answer (score 3):

tl; dr: The term *smooth* gets used inconsistently. As elsewhere in mathematics, the words-to-concepts relation is not a mapping; the same word can mean multiple things.

To be careful with terminology here, it might be best to say the mapping $r(t) = (t^{3}, t^{3})$ is *infinitely differentiable*, but *not regular* at $t = 0$.

---

1. In differential topology, the term *smooth mapping* generally connotes some degree of differentiability, often infinite differentiability.
2. In differential topology and differential geometry, the term *smooth manifold* connotes a manifold with a smooth atlas (whose overlap maps are smooth). A *smooth submanifold* is a smooth manifold together with a smooth embedding into, e.g., a Cartesian space.
3. In differential geometry, one sometimes uses the term *regular mapping* to connote a smooth immersion (a smooth mapping $f:M \to N$ from a smooth manifold into a manifold of equal or larger dimension whose differential $Df$ has rank $\dim M$ at each point). At other times (::cough:: ::cough:: *calculus books*, and sometimes elementary textbooks on differential geometry), one encounters the term *smooth mapping* conveying that the mapping is regular, or that the *image* is a smooth submanifold.